# Accessing Hashtable in Class and its elements, Java

Tags: java, class, object, hashtable

I have a class "Item" which contains the following...

```
public class Item{

    private String barcode;

    private String productName;

    private int quantity;

}
```

I also have a class named "Store" that was to contain my HashTable like so...

```
public class Store implements Serializable{

Hashtable<String, Item> store = new Hashtable<String, Item>();

}
```

The String would be the same as the barcode and be the "key" for the Item Objects in the HashTable.

Now in my main I am trying to create Instances of these Class Objects and store the Items in the Hashtable using the put() method but I can't seem to access it. I want to add items to the Hashtable and if it finds that the item is already there, it increments the items quantity value.

I have zero experience with HashTables, can anyone help?

EDIT:

Code in my main...

```
Store store = new Store();

    Item item1 = new Item();
    item1.setProductName("Paper Towel Roll");
    item1.setBarCode("111222333444");
    item1.setQuantity(1);

    store.put("111222333444", item1);
```

Comment: Javadoc and google can...

Comment: Been doing that, I can't find my case. I've seen something similar to mine but the Hashtable was declared within main. Whats the purpose of the Class then?

Comment: Have you defined `hashCode` and `equals` for your `Item` type?  Also, I would *strongly* suggest using `HashMap` instead of `Hashtable`; `Hashtable` is now frowned upon.

Comment: No I have not, also I have to use Hashtables

Comment: Would I use the hashCode function as my "key" ?

Comment: show us your main. wild guess: you try to access your non public `HashTable` from outside your Store class

Comment: I've added some code that is in my main.

Comment: You're treating your Store object like it is a hashtable...but it actually contains one. You need to either a) make a setter for the hash table (which should probably be named stockedItems instead) like addItem b) make your hashtable public and access it directly (would be store.store.put in your example) c) extend a hashtable (which seems to be what you're trying to do by directly calling "put" on your Store object)

Comment: Since HashTable already has functions like put that do the adding and removing etc. I should just leave it as it and access it directly via something like "store.store.put()". That'll prolly work best.

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
public class Store implements Serializable{
 public Hashtable<String, Item> itemsTable = new Hashtable<String, Item>();
}
```

And in main:

```
Store store = new Store();

Item item1 = new Item();
item1.setProductName("Paper Towel Roll");
item1.setBarCode("111222333444");
item1.setQuantity(1);

store.itemsTable.put("111222333444", item1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Public so you can access it out of the package. Its in "package-private" because there is no modifier specified.

```
public class Store implements Serializable{

    private Hashtable<String, Item> items = new Hashtable<String, Item>();

    // Getter and setter for items hashtable

}
```

Main Code:

```
Store store = new Store();

Item item1 = new Item();
item1.setProductName("Paper Towel Roll");
item1.setBarCode("111222333444");
item1.setQuantity(1);

// NOTE: getItems() is the getter for the store object. 
// Don't expose it as public. Bad encapsulation

store.getItems().put(item1.getBarCode(), item1);
```

NOTE: Its best to avoid Hashtable and Use HashMap instead

Comment: Use Hashtable if you need synchronized object.

Comment: Its still better to use Collections.synchronizedMap